# What is lto1.exe?

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

when you inspect mingw you will find the c compiler cc1.exe (funny growing in size in 9.2 it is almost 25 MB ) cc1plus.exe is c++ compiler (same sizes) collect2.exe is linker (afiak) nut what is lto1.exe?

i googled for it more than hour but not found info on this.. is there some good info on this avaliable to read? tnx

ps. i suspect that it may be related to link time optimisation but found nothing more about it and i would like to know better

there is also a question what is gcc.exe g++.exe and mingw32-gcc.exe mingw32-g++.exe then

i need more informatin, the most the better , tnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not mingw / Windos specific; it's a feature / component of GCC.

> what is lto1.exe?

It's the lto compiler :o). lto is basically byte code written when compiled with [`-flto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-flto) where "lto" or "LTO" stands for "link-time optimization".

These optimizations are *not* performed by the linker but by the compiler at *link time* to perform global optimizations when (byte-)code from all the modules is available.  The flow is as follows:

1. The C/C++ compiler (`cc1` for C or `cc1plus` for C++) compiles C/C++ to byte-code and writes it to the assembly file `*.s`.
2. Assembly is assembled by the assembler to object code `*.o` as usual. lto-code is shipped in dedicated sections.
3. At link time, the linker (plugin) calls back the compiler and supplies all the objects and libraries as requested.  byte-code is extracted, and the `lto1` compiler compiles it to final machine code.
4. The final machine code is assembled by the assembler to object code.
5. The linker links / locates these objects to final executable code.

You see the byte-code in the lto sections with [`-save-temps`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-save-temps) and having a look at the saved `*.s` files.  Recent versions of GCC don't even bother with writing assembly code; they are just writing lto code.  To see the assembly code, specify [`-ffat-lto-objects`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ffat-lto-objects).  Notice however that this is *not* the final code.

> funny growing in size in 9.2 it is almost 25 MB

The sizes of GCC executables depend not only on the GCC major version, but also highly on how well the compiler used to build GCC is optimizing.

[Edit] Some information on LTO can be found on the [GCC wiki for LTO](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization). Notice however that this page is no more active.  One goto place for gory GCC internals is the [gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org  mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html#subscribe) where all the developers are.  There is also a section about [LTO in the GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html).

Comment: do you maybe have some links on that?

Comment: Added more links in [EDIT] above.  What exactly are you looking for? How lto code is structured?  How to use LTO? Compiler sources?

Comment: i would like to know what it ias as for now i understand its not a linker but a language agnostic compiler 'backend'? Do you know maybe what gcc.exe and mingw32-gcc.exe is then?

Comment: lto1 is a lto compiler just like cc1 is a C compiler and cc1plus is a C++ compiler. GCC has different front-ends, that is code which reads / interprets one input language and provides the generated internal representation to the middle-end (language- and target-independent passes). lto front-end is one of them. The difference is that lto is byte gibberish produced by the compiler, wheras the compiler proper for C/C++ reads text files written by programmers, usually after preprocessing.

Comment: The `gcc` executable is not a compiler by itself, it's just a driver program that calls sub-commands like preprocessor, compiler proper, assembler (`as`) and linker (`ld`) depending on options and file extensions. You see the sub-commands being run with `gcc -v ...`.